# How to Print Listed invoices each on another (different) Page in C# windows form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview, invoice

Scenario:

I am working on Windows form Application where i have a today sale report in datagridview and after selecting invoiceID in for loop from datagridview I have to print invoices but each invoice on different page.
**How can i shift to next page while printing.**

My Code :

```
private void prnDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

 CurrentY = 50;
 CurrentX = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < dgvViewGeneralSaleReport.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (dgvViewGeneralSaleReport.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != " ")
            {

              invoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvViewGeneralSaleReport.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim());
                 //// invoice design Start

                leftMargin = 20;
                //  rightMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Right;
                rightMargin = 830;
                topMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Top;
                bottomMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Bottom;
                InvoiceWidth = (int)e.MarginBounds.Width;
                InvoiceHeight = (int)e.MarginBounds.Height;

                if (!ReadInvoice)
                    ReadInvoiceData();
                SetInvoiceHead(e.Graphics); // Draw Invoice Head
                SetOrderData(e.Graphics); // Draw Order Data
                SetInvoiceData(e.Graphics, e); // Draw Invoice Data

                //// invoice design End

                ReadInvoice = true;
                e.HasMorePages = true;


           CurrentY = 50;
           CurrentX = 100;

            }
            else
            {
                StopReading = true;
                ReadInvoice = false;
                e.HasMorePages = false;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your loop outside of the `PrintPage` method.  The call you make to start the printing needs to be the one in the loop.

Basically...

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvViewGeneralSaleReport.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dgvViewGeneralSaleReport.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != " ")
        printDocument.Print();
}
```

Within the `PrintPage` method, continue to do all of the same things you are now, only that you will also have to maintain awareness of which page you are printing.

The important point here is that it's the individual call to `PrintPage` that defines the page.  The control variable `e.HasMorePages` is the way you tell it to keep going.

Comment: that's ok but i have to see all invoices in print preview too.

Comment: Why wouldn't you?  Until `e.HasMorePages` is false, pages are generated.  Regardless of what you are printing to.  If you only see one, then you are using the preview control incorrectly.

Comment: i am using e.HasMorePages for keep going, i can see preview of one single page if i drop out the for loop but don't when i use for loop

Comment: i want to call print event only one time so that all invoices should be seen in one print preview dialog.